# Full justify paragraph in Illustrator (Part of the word out of text box)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, paragraph, formatting

I am up to full justify paragraph in Illustrator CS5, but there is a line which goes off the text box. I use text boxes, and set full justify. Settings for Justification window are recommended:

Word spacing   80,100,133

Letter Spacing     -3,0,3

Glyph Scaling  97,100,103

The problem persists no matter of ***Single Line/Every line*** choice. I've tied to fix it with kerning, but the last word in line is nailed to this position. 
How to solve this, and could it be a problem with the actual font (setting during creating a font)? Thanks!

[image][image]

Comment: This would drive me insane. I'm afraid it may be a CS5 bug, but tech support for CS5 is going to be a hard thing to get out of Adobe.

Comment: I've managed in the meantime to try with Illustrator CC, and same paragraph looks fine in it. So you are right, it seems that this is CS5 bug :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to trick the text box into pushing this word onto the next line by using Text Wrap. Try placing an object (invisible if necessary) to the right of the text box and edit this object's left sided Text Wrap margin.

Comment: It works! New object must be one line height to avoid pushing adjacent lines, and that's it! Many thanks for your help